# Proving the convergence of a sequence $e_{n+1}=e_n e_{n-1}$

Tags: number-theory, analysis, inequality, convergence-divergence

The sequence $e_n$ has limit $0$ and all terms are in $(0,1)$. Also, we have that $e_{n+1}=e_n e_{n-1}$
I need to show that we can pick $C$ s.t.

$$e_{n+1}\le C \cdot  e_n^\phi$$

where $\phi$ is the golden ratio. Any ideas? As all terms are in $(0,1)$ so we know that $e_{n+1}<\min(e_n,e_{n-1})$ but I'm not sure where to go.

Comment: better is to write $$a_{n+1}=a_n\cdot a_{n-1}$$ since $e$ is the Eulerian number

Comment: the solution is given by $$a_n=e^{C_1Fibonacci_n+C_2LucasL_n}$$

Comment: Take logarithms and define $b_n=\log(e_n)$ to come to something you know.

Comment: Okay, That makes a lot of sense; so we have that $b_n$ is the fibonacci sequence. I'm still not quite sure how we get the term by term result instead of the upper bound on the growth though, could you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_0 = \alpha$, $a_1 = \beta$. By induction, $a_n = \alpha^{F_{n-1}}\beta^{F_n}$ for $n\ge 2$, where $F_n$ is the Fibonacci sequence with $F_0 = 0$. It is a well known fact that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{F_n}{F_{n-1}} =\phi$. Moreover even $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} |F_n - \phi F_{n-1}| = 0^{[1]}$

$$ \text{Thus  }\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n^\phi} = \alpha^{F_n-\phi F_{n-1}} \beta ^{F_{n+1}-\phi F_n}= 1 $$

It follows that $C = \sup\{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n^\phi} \mid n\in\mathbb N\} < \infty$, implying the inequality.

$^{[1]}$ The former does not imply the latter, for example take $a_n = n$. It is however generally a consequence for sequences that are exponential in first order. In the case at hand it follows directly from [Binet's formula](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Binet%27s_Formula)